# RegExMatch doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, regular-expressions

I am trying to strip anything including angle brackets out from a string of text via Regular Expressions.

I have the below variable set:

```
set @messageText = 'Hello, Chris John,<br><br>John Doe(CP Admin), an assister from Kentucky, is requesting access to your information, including resources, benefits, household information, etc., to better assist you with your needs.To grant access, please click<br><br>Regards,<br>Resource Engine<br><br>Note: this is an automatic message.'
```

Then, I have a RegExMatch function call:

```
set @regex = "\<.*?\>"
set @outputMessageText = RegExMatch(@messageText, @regex, 0)
```

Finally, I try to output `@outputMessageText`:

outputMessageText = `%%=v(@outputMessageText)=%%`

The result is:

outputMessageText =

Notice it's blank. Is there something wrong with my Regular Expression?

Answer (score 5):

Your regExmatch function is just going to return the match (in rendered HTML in your case), not do the replacements.  Your pattern looks fine.

```ampscript
%%[

set @regEx = "<(.*?)>"
set @str = "Hello, Chris John,<br><br>John Doe(CP Admin), an assister from Kentucky, is requesting access to your information, including resources, benefits, household information, etc., to better assist you with your needs.To grant access, please click<br><br>Regards,<br>Resource Engine<br><br>Note: this is an automatic message."
set @result = RegExMatch(@str, @regEx, 0) /* find the match */
set @replace = replace(@str, @result," ") /* replace the matches */
output(concat("<br>result:", replace(replace(@result,"<","&lt;"),">","&gt;"))) /* escape the tag symbols for output */
output(concat("<br>replace:", @replace))

]%%
```

**Output**

```
result:<br>
replace:Hello, Chris John, John Doe(CP Admin), an assister from Kentucky, is requesting access to your information, including resources, benefits, household information, etc., to better assist you with your needs.To grant access, please click Regards, Resource Engine Note: this is an automatic message.
```